# How to convert a fixed width file to XML file?

Tags: xml

I have a fixed width text file to convert to XML. Can you tell me how to make it in detail?

My sample text looks like this...

```
9621120080828200808290001084713CENTRAL TIONG NAM WAREHOUSE        086014286100501330071881000020000000000000090002PC       20.000       20.000 81E0       600.000         20.000           PC UB                      
9621120080828200808290001084713CENTRAL TIONG NAM WAREHOUSE        086014286100501330071881900001000000000000011131PC     1000.000    24000.000 8100     13680.000       1920.000 47/2008   CRTUB  00100000000003346495
```

from the first line I want to convert text file based on length..

- 1st 5 characters to `File No` i.e  `96211`
- next 8 chars to `Shipment Creation Date` i.e `20080828`
- next 8 chars to `Delivery Date` i.e `20080829` and so on...

Note : first two lines is considered as one record.....

I want the output like below

```
<FileNo>96211<FileNo>
<ShipmentCreationDate>20080828<ShipmentCreationDate>
<DeliveryDate>20080829<DeliveryDate>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( { } ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Also: **do not** use spaces in your XML tags!! That will either cause a lot of grief, or not work at all - just don't do it!

Answer (score 4):

I would urge you to have a look at the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) library.

It's a C# library that allows you to import fixed-width or delimited files into C# very quickly.

You can then easily turn around and spit out those records as XML from your C# - no problem at all!

In detail:

- using FileHelpers, you would define a class that represents your data (one line of it)
- FileHelpers then imports the contents of a file into an array of objects of that class
- using `XmlSerializer`, you can then easily serialize those objects back out to XML

Should be about 50 lines or less of code :-)

Comment: How do you know that he is using C#?

Comment: @karsten: just guessing or hoping! :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no control over the outputting Application you will have to write a converter tool.

Take your preferend language and matching XML-Lib and write a small application which parses the data and writes it as XML.